# Counting average number of repeated variables

Tags: count, sas, average, frequency

I have a dataset of unique patient IDs (~250,000) that includes repeats. I want to count the average number of times each unique RID appears. I can only figure out how to count the actual number of times each unique RID appears using:

```
proc freq data=patients;
tables rid;
run;
```

IE: I do not want to know that 

RID 1 appears 2 
RID 2 appears 4 
RID 3 appears 3

I want to know that the average number that a unique RID appears is 3.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this via PROC SQL

```
Select count(*)/count(distinct rid)
from patients;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically that is total number of records divided by unique number of RIDs.

You can use SQL with a COUNT DISTINCT and COUNT to accomplish this in a single step.